# Awkward sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

- A clause having a subject beginning with preposition is used occasionally.

Does this sentence make any sense? I think this sentence means that **a clause** has a **subject phrase** that was started with preposition, and such kind of clause is used occasionally.

Please say what you think. I want better way to rewrite the sentence stated above.

Comment: *A clause which has a subject that begins with a preposition is used occasionally.*

Comment: Thanks for your sentence. Do you think that the given example is wrong?

Comment: I think is understandable but poorly rephrased.

Comment: A clause having a subject that starts with preposition is used occasionally- does it sound natural? Or is it a good sentence?

Comment: I can't confim whether it sounds natural or not since I'm not a native speaker but most of books use *begin* instead of *start* when writing sentences.

Answer (score 3):

Is a more natural sounding sentence is

> A clause having a subject beginning with **a** preposition is used occasionally.

without the **a** you will sound non-native.

This sentence is fine:

> Does this sentence make any sense?

As per @Subjunctive:

> I think this sentence means that a clause has a subject phrase that **begins** with **a** preposition

because you are asking about a collection (of types of clauses):

> and such **types** of clause**s are** used occasionally

Since you are wondering about how to improve your sentence:

> I would like **a** better way rewriting this sentence, **please suggest any improvements**.

Although what you wrote is understandable:

> Please say what you think.

is asking for an **opinion**, whereas you are asking for **suggestions**, and again the **a**:

> I want **a** better way to rewrite the sentence stated above

without which to a native ear will signal you as a non-native speaker